# Model в Site.master

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Здравствуйте. У меня возник вопрос по asp.net mvc 2.
У меня есть страница Site.Master на которой отображаются общие для всех страниц элементы, например меню. Меню должно заполняться динамически из модели которую получаем из БД. Вопрос - как мне воспользоваться моделью на этой странице? Откуда мне эту модель передавать? Может я объясняю не очень внятно, но надеюсь, что кому-нибудь мой вопрос будет понятен. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использует `<% Html.RenderAction("ActionName"); %>`
Внутри данного экшена обращайтесь к базе и стройте ViewModel для вашего PartialView который, собственно, и возвращайте из экшена.

Comment: большое спасибо! Вы меня спасли))